# Can I access repeated post variables in PHP without '[]' in the name?

Tags: php, post

Say there is a form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input name='foo'>
    <input name='foo'>
    <input type=submit>
</form>
```

posting to my php script. How (if at all) can I find out the two values submitted in these boxes. `$_POST['foo']` gives the second value, but I want both.

I realize this can be done by using `<input name='foo[]'>` (which would make `$_POST['foo']` an array). Due to certain coding decisions adding the square brackets is undesirable (read: would require some restructuring), and it seems that there should be an easy way to do this.

If the enctype was 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' then parsing it would be easy, but "multipart/form-data" is more complex and could have a 30MB file in it!

Not to mention PHP has already parsed the post data.

Please can someone tell me that PHP kept that information that it parsed from $_POST and that I can access it without re-parsing.

Thanks!

Comment: You can name them foo and foo2 that would allow you to send both. But you won't be getting it with the way they are named.

Comment: Surely it would only take a little extra logic to implement foo[]?

Comment: @Sam152 You'd think/hope, but there is a whole system for generating the html form elements and matching them with the posted data. Which would have been fine except for all the small problems like this. A quick n dirty hack would do the trick, but I'd rather do it properly (which is what would take the time).

Comment: @mikevoermans We'll also need to process `<select multiple=multiple>`, so that won't solve the whole problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't access it, and `$_POST` won't keep it.  If the browser even sent it (which it should have), the array key would be overwritten when it is parsed into the `$_POST` superglobal from the HTTP request.

It's sort of equivalent to defining an array like:

```
array(
  'one' => 1,
  'two' => 2,
  'one' => 3
);

Array(2) {
  ["one"]=>
      int(3)
  ["two"]=>
      int(2)
}
```

The array key `one` is set initially, but when another value is encountered during the initialization, it is immediately overwritten.

#### Not great for your situation (multipart form) but applicable to future readers:

If you read in the entire raw HTTP POST, you may be able to parse out the value you need.

```
<?php $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input"); ?>
```

This would give you a string like

```
 foo=value1&foo=value2
```

You can't pass it to `parse_str()` though, as you'll run into the same array key overwrite problem. You would have to do string parsing to pull out the other value.

It really is easier to change them to an array with `[]` if possible.

Comment: That is what I assumed PHP was doing, but I hoped it had a more sophisticated approach that would keep all the data it poured into $_POST.

Comment: @DaedalusFall It might be possible to read it from the raw HTTP POST.

Comment: After update: That was my first though, but as stated in the question its multipart/form-data encoded so it won't look like `foo=value1&foo=value2`, and as there are actually file imputs in the real form we could be parsing megabytes of data. Doable, certainly, but annoying (and definately more work than '[]'). This would probably be easier if http://php.net/ hadn't been inaccessible all day :).